# How do you escape raw HTML in Go?

Tags: html, go, escaping

I have managed to output text using the following line:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "<p>some text</p>")
```

But this will literally output the HTML tags. How do you output it so it can safely be included in HTML like you would with `echo` in PHP?

Comment: The templating in go is so simple to use, I wouldn't even bother with trying to output html in any other way.

Comment: I am trying to create a web server in go

Comment: Take a look at http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/ - you should render data to a template. The template/html library also takes care of handling 'user data' safely to avoid XSS. http://jan.newmarch.name/go/template/chapter-template.html is a good primer for learning the package.

Answer (score 3):

[`fmt.Fprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf) has no knowledge of HTML syntax: it outputs raw data without escaping it (it may do some formatting but that is not escaping).

You don't use it correctly though: its second parameter is a format string, so you should call it rather like this:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", "<p>some text</p>")
```

Else if your text contains some format-specific special characters, you will not get the expected result.

What you want is to escape HTML code so it can be safely included in HTML documents/pages. For that you get excellent support from the [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package which provides you a powerful template engine where automatic escaping functionality being just one feature.

Here's a simple example how to achieve what you want:

```
w := os.Stdout

text := "<p>some text</p>"
fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", text)

tt := `{{.}}`
t := template.Must(template.New("test").Parse(tt))
t.Execute(w, text)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/khD53iVQeJ)):

```
<p>some text</p>
&lt;p&gt;some text&lt;/p&gt;
```

Also note that if you only want to escape some HTML code, there is a [`template.HTMLEscaper()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTMLEscaper) function for that:

```
fmt.Println(template.HTMLEscaper(text))
```

Output:

```
&lt;p&gt;some text&lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: `"<p>some text</p>" *is* a format string, just one that consists entirely of literal characters.

Comment: @JohnGowers Whether a string is interpreted as a format string depends on where you pass it to. If you pass it as the 2nd argument to `fmt.Fprintf()`, yes, it will be interpreted as that, yet, it's not the intention of the asker. The asker just wants to output this string, and thus using a format string `"%s"` and passing this text as an argument will be more efficient as this string will not be analyzes / interpreted, just outputted as is. Also if it would contain `%` for example, the output could be entirely different than intended.

Comment: @JohnGowers Also using `fmt.Fprint()` would be more efficient as that doesn't even use format string, and it doesn't attempt to interpret the string, just writes it to the output. And if the asker wants to substitute parameters into the string, `html/template` is a superior solution as that implements context sensitive escaping, safe against code injection.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was not the output method that i used. Atchaully, the browser is seeing it as plain text instead of html. Therefore you need to tell the browser that it is html.

```
 w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
```

This function simply sets the content type to html.

Comment: I'm curious now as to why this didn't work for you.  The presence of the `<p>` tag should be enough for Go's `DetectContentType` function to detect that the text is in HTML format.  See here for a description of the algorithm used: https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#identifying-a-resource-with-an-unknown-mime-type